# Http Call to a Non-spring Application from a Spring Application

Tags: spring, http, request

I am working on a spring application which has to make a HTTP call to another applciation (not running on Spring). How can i make this call using spring framework?

**Note**: I cannot use Spring's HTTP Invokers as the application i am calling is not on spring.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is language and framework agnostic, you don't need Spring (or even Java) both on the client and on the server side. Here is an example code fetching data using HTTP and printing them to console:

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(
    new URL("http://www.google.com").openStream(),
    System.out);
```

**Note:** you don't need `IOUtils` from Apache Commons IO  as well, here just to shorten the example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to make the HTTP calls easily... or if they are Restful web services, you can use [Spring's RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) to make the calls.

Comment: I do not want to use apache httpclient. I am looking for something as part of springframe work itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SOAP (web service)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html) implementation by spring.

Comment: Mine is a simple rest call. why the overhead of webservice?